# Creating complex concave polygonal surface from points in vtk

Tags: python, c++, vtk

I am working on a project where I need to generate surfaces from user-defined points to create polygons. For convex polygons, I am able to generate surfaces using the Delaunay2D triangulation method without any issues. However, when I try to generate surfaces for concave polygons, I am encountering some problems.

For example, when I define points on a concave polygon, such as the one shown in the image below, and generate a surface using Delaunay2D, I get a filled surface that does not accurately represent the polygon:

[image: Points on a concave polygon]

[image: Surface generated using vtkDelaunay2D]

I have tried many other methods for surface generation, but I have not been able to figure out the right way to perform surface generation for concave polygons.

Can anyone suggest a method for generating surfaces from user-defined points for concave polygons? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you facing any problems with C++ or Python code? If not, please remove those tags.

Comment: A Delaunay triangulation is defined on a *point set on a plane*. It has no idea about your polygon. Why do you ever need a Delaunay triangulation? If you have a polygon, you *probably* need to triangulate the polygon (this has nothing to do with Delaunay).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want the "concave hull" of a set of points. The problem is there is not a natural definition of what this would be. While there is one well-defined convex hull of a set of points, there are many concave hulls. Choosing one of them that is suitable depends on what it is you are doing.

[See for example this question on the GIS stackexchange.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull)

All of that said, however, I have found that the algorithm described in ["Efficient generation of simple polygons for characterizing the shape of a set of points in the plane"](http://www.geosensor.net/papers/duckham08.PR.pdf) by Duckham et. al. yields concave hulls that are useful in practice. The algorithm is basically to start with a Delaunay triangulation of the points and then remove external edges from the triangulation until there is no edge that can be removed that is longer than *x*, where *x* is an input parameter you choose according to your use case. The paper in the above link describes how to do this in an efficient manner.

[Python implementation here.](https://github.com/damienmarlier51/PolygonX)

Comment: Hi jwezorek, Thank you for the suggestion, I will check this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [following](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo):

```py
from vedo import * 
from vedo.applications import SplinePlotter
pic = Picture("image.png")
plt = SplinePlotter(pic)  # interactively place points
plt.show(mode="image", zoom='tight')
msh = plt.line.generate_mesh().smooth()
plt.close()
show(msh, axes=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you mmusy, I will try this approach. I have also found that we can use `vtkContourTriangulator` to generate the surface [https://discourse.vtk.org/t/creating-complex-concave-polygonal-surface-from-points/10959/8] (VTK Discourse) answered by David Gobbi.

Comment: yes, that's even easier, add `plt.closed = True` and substitute `generate_mesh ` with `triangulate`.